# ContractInstance.method is undefined

Tags: contract-development, dapp-development

When I use `contractInstance.getDrawStats` or any other method it returns error `method is not a function` because of contractInstance doesn't contain any contract methods. However, they are definitely in ABI.

I'm using Metamask as web3 provider

There is my contract api

```
const factoryAddress = "0x36a3ce90ba3e96859eca2e77af280fe2fdbd4765"; 

const factoryABI = require("./api/Factory.json");



let factory;


let factoryContract;

window.App = {
    init: function() {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        factory = web3.eth.contract(factoryABI).at(factoryAddress);
        console.log('Complete');
    },

    createLottery: function(drawsAmount) {
        factory.createLottery(drawsAmount, (error, result) => {console.log(result)});
    }
};

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        console.log("MetaMask detected")
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        App.init();
    } else {
        console.warn("MetaMask not found")
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ["call"](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call) if it does not require to be mined, or ["send"](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send) if it needs to be mined:

Comment: Because of contractInstance.anyMethod is undefined, "call" or "send" cannot be used. There is a problem with the wrong creation of contract instance using MetaMask web3